# How to fix Google Chrome crashes whenever i try to open an incognito tab

Tags: google-chrome, crash-reports

Google chrome crashes whenever I try to open up an incognito tab. Whenever i try to ctrl shift n or alternative ways, google chrome shuts down and I have to restart it. I'm on google 123.0.6312.4.

I've tried reinstalling chrome, resetting settings, turning off graphics acceleration, and deleting every chrome file and then reinstalling it. I've also tried updating chrome. This problem is limited to only 1 google account. The others work fine. This happened before when my computer shut down suddenly, and it appears chrome corrupted. Before, if I tried to open incognito on Chrome multiple times, it would work. However, this time, after the computer shut down again, incognito is not able to be opened up at all. I think it's a problem with chrome.dll, but how do I fix it?

STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  chrome+1bc930

MODULE_NAME: chrome

IMAGE_NAME:  chrome.dll

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_c0000005_chrome.dll!Unknown

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  123.0.6312.4

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {74d388af-6d1f-21b1-987e-9640e41d45b8}